# How to allow online renewals for memberships created in the backend?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

If you created a membership in the admin section, the member is not able to renew the membership using their dashboard.

If you have a link on your site for that membership sign up, the user can renew by going there. But if for some reason there's no public link, it is hard for the user to renew.

This may be the case if you have multiple memberships, with some that are not available to the general public.

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the contribution so that the system knows which online page needs to be used for renewal. Steps:

Add the membership & payment (must add a payment, $0 works)

Edit the payment - In the Additional details section, choose the appropriate Online contribution page